# Removing dots from filenames excluding the last dot SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access.

In a table one of the column is `FileName`. Each row of this column contains a different filename with an extension. For example

- `099.112.flower.jpeg`,
- `100.133.batman.mov`,
- `101.144.study.pdf`, etc.

Please suggest me on a query which could help me to remove the dots excluding from the file extension. So that I could fetch only the name and the extension:

- `099112flower.jpeg`,
- `100133batman.mov`,
- `101144study.pdf`, etc.

Comment: you need to show us what you tried so far

Comment: At first place Im not sure how to approach this problem. Please advice if you have any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Well, your job is it to think about the problem, articulate a proposed solution, and then try and solve it on your own. You must have at least a bit of an idea what you could do.

Answer (score 1):

You could have some fun with Replace and InstrReverse for an expression:

```
NewFilename: Replace(Replace(StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse([FileName]), ".", "¤", 1, 1)), ".", ""), "¤", ".")
```

If it seems OK in a select query, apply it in your update query.

Answer (score 0):

table = the table you want to update
column1 = the column name you want to update

UPDATE [table] SET [column1] = RIGHT([column1],LEN([column1])-InStr(1,[IPAddress],".")+1)